# Get data to related Date in an array

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, mongodb, vue.js

i want to get the numbers of single jobs from different rows.
Relevant for that are the columns "created_at" and "data" which is an JSON Array with all the single Jobs in it which have to be count.

Now i want to count the number of all the jobs ($countAllJobs) and the number of the Jobs which are done ($countDoneJobs) for every single day which got selected.

One of my Problems is that i don't now how to seperate the counted values from each other by their created_at, so that all rows with the same date will be counted for that specific day, even if the time (H:i:s) in the created_at is different.

I'm pushing the data wrong to the array but i can't figure it out:

```
        `$statistics    = Jobs::select('data', 'created_at')
                        ->whereBetween('created_at', ['2023-01-09', '2023-01-20 06:59:00'])
                        ->get();

        $jobs = [];

        $countAllJobs = 0;
        $countDoneJobs = 0;


        foreach($statistics as $s) {

            $jobs[$s->created_at] = [];

            $obj = json_decode($s->data, true);

            foreach ($obj as $o) {

                $countAllJobs += 1;

                if ($o['status'] == 'ok') {

                    $countDoneJobs += 1;
                }

                $jobs = ['allJobs' => $countAllJobs ,'doneJobs' => $countDoneJobs];
            }
        }`
```

I'm working with laravel and MongoDB. The result will be printed out in a statistic in vue.js

I hope i made the question clear

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

assuming your done jobs have the value of `ok` from `data` column and key `status`.

you can do all the calculation in your query.

e.i this uses `now` function which uses carbon date

```
$fromDate = now()->subDays(11); // past 11 days from current date
$toDate = now(); 

return Jobs::selectRaw('Date(created_at) as date') // select date format Y-m-d
    ->selectRaw('count(created_at) AS allJobs')   //count result based on grouping
    ->selectRaw("Sum(CASE WHEN json_unquote(json_extract(`data`, '$.status')) = 'ok' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS doneJobs") // sum all result that has value of data->status = ok
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$fromDate, $toDate] ) //filter created_at from  the past 11 days up to current date
    ->groupBy('date') // group the result by date
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
but i get just NULL as results for everything..
Like the query is not working at all, is it because of mongoDB ?

Comment: post your table structure

Comment: i solved my problem. I just had to format the created_at with Carbon so i could count the jobs with the same date.
I could'nt use youre query because of mongoDb, otherwise it would have worked.
But thanks for the help !